# Testing for a maximum unsigned value

Tags: c++, c, unsigned

Is this the correct way to test for a maximum unsigned value in C and C++ code:

```
if(foo == -1)
{
    // at max possible value
}
```

where foo is an `unsigned int`, an `unsigned short`, and so on.

Comment: I agree with all the answers below regarding if statements.  However, for for/while loops it can be a good idea to use -1.

Comment: Wish that comments could be negged.  Will have to be content with a flag I guess.

Comment: @Noah: flagging is NOT a way to express disagreement with a comment which is on topic and polite.

Answer (score 13):

For C++, I believe you should preferably use the `numeric_limits` template from the [`<limits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) header :

```
if (foo == std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max())
    /* ... */
```

For C, others have already pointed out the [`<limits.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) header and `UINT_MAX`.

---

Apparently, "solutions which are allowed to name the type are easy", so you can have :

```
template<class T>
inline bool is_max_value(const T t)
{
    return t == std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
}

[...]

if (is_max_value(foo))
    /* ... */
```

Comment: @Noah: Wrong.  The standard requires that integral values converted to unsigned be done congruent 2**n.  See `[conv.integral]`.

Comment: But foo might be `unsigned short`.  Solutions which are allowed to name the type are easy.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that you ask this question since at a certain point you don't know the concrete type of your variable `foo`, otherwise you naturally would use `UINT_MAX` etc.

For C your approach is the right one only for types with a conversion rank of `int` or higher. This is because before being compared an `unsigned short` value, e.g, is first converted to `int`, if all values fit, or to `unsigned int` otherwise. So then your value `foo` would be compared either to `-1` or to `UINT_MAX`, not what you expect.

I don't see an easy way of implementing the test that you want in C, since basically using `foo` in any type of expression would promote it to `int`.

With gcc's `typeof` extension this is easily possible. You'd just have to do something like

```
if (foo == (typeof(foo))-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

As already noted, you should probably use `if (foo == std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max())` to get the value.

However for completeness, in C++ `-1` is "probably" guaranteed to be the max unsigned value when converted to unsigned (this wouldn't be the case if there were unused bit patterns at the upper end of the unsigned value range).

See 4.7/2:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the
>   least unsigned integer congruent to
>   the source integer (modulo 2^n where n
>   is the number of bits used to
>   represent the unsigned type). [Note:
>   In a two’s complement representation,
>   this conversion is conceptual and
>   there is no change in the bit pattern
>   (if there  is no truncation). ]

Note that specifically for the `unsigned int` case, due to the rules in 5/9 it appears that if either operand is unsigned, the other will be converted to unsigned automatically so you don't even need to cast the `-1` (if I'm reading the standard correctly). In the case of unsigned short you'll need a direct check or explicit cast because of the automatic integral promotion induced by the `==`.

Comment: @Noah: You're wrong. It is completely guaranteed. C and C++ both define conversion to unsigned types as taking place modulo the maximum unsigned value plus one.

Answer (score 1):

using `#include <limits.h>` you could just do

`if(foo == UINT_MAX)`

if foo is an `unsigned int` it has valued [0 - +4,294,967,295] (if 32 bit)

More : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h

edit: in `C`

if you do

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int x = -1;
    printf("%u",x);
    return 0;
}
```

you will get the result `4294967295` (in a 32-bit system) and that is because internally, -1 is represented by `11111111111111111111111111111111` in two's complement. But because it is an `unsigned`, there is now no "sign bit" therefore making it work in the range [0-2^n]

Also see : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

See other's answers for the `C++` part `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`

Answer (score 0):

I would define a constant that would hold the maximum value as needed by the design of your code. Using "-1" is confusing. Imagine that someone in the future will change the type from unsigned int to int, it will mess your code.

Comment: Changing the signedness of a variable without looking at all the implications will cause **a lot** more problems than this, so I don't see how that's an argument against using -1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at doing this in C. It depends on the implementation not having padding bits:

```
#define IS_MAX_UNSIGNED(x) ( (sizeof(x)>=sizeof(int)) ? ((x)==-1) : \
                             ((x)==(1<<CHAR_BIT*sizeof(x))-1) )
```

Or, if you can modify the variable, just do something like:

```
if (!(x++,x--)) { /* x is at max possible value */ }
```

**Edit:** And if you don't care about possible implementation-defined extended integer types:

```
#define IS_MAX_UNSIGNED(x) ( (sizeof(x)>=sizeof(int)) ? ((x)==-1) : \
                             (sizeof(x)==sizeof(short)) ? ((x)==USHRT_MAX) : \
                             (sizeof(x)==1 ? ((x)==UCHAR_MAX) : 42 )
```

You could use `sizeof(char)` in the last line, of course, but I consider it a code smell and would typically catch it grepping for code smells, so I just wrote 1. Of course you could also just remove the last conditional entirely.

Comment: +1 for giving for ideas that almost always work... To capture more weirdo cases: in `IS_MAX_UNSIGNED` for the second comparison I would shift `1u`, not `1`, to be sure that `x` is converted to `unsigned`. Then your solution even works if `signed` has padding bits.

Comment: I'm not sure that offers any benefit. Don't corresponding signed and unsigned types always have the same number of padding bits? My impression was that various parts of the standard together imply that `UINT_MAX==2U*INT_MAX+1` and likewise for other types, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Added a new possible solution.

Comment: @Roland: the shift is unevaluated unless `sizeof (x) < sizeof (int)`.  So there's no problem.

Comment: Thanks Ben. That's what I was going to say.

Comment: @R, @Ben, ok, the shift should work then. But R., I don't think that your impression about padding bits is correct. I think that the sign bit is allowed to be among the padding bits of the unsigned type, or stated differently, the implementation is allowed to mask out the sign bit for the signed type. AFAICS the only types for which this is not allowed are `{un}signed char`.

Comment: @Jens: Then what would `(unsigned_type)-1` evaluate to?  According to the standard, it must be "congruent to the source integer (modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type)", which can only be ALL bits set to `1`.  Padding bits are illegal.

Comment: @Ben, in the contrary padding bits are explicitly allowed. The only restrictions are `unsigned char` and the `uintxx_t`, but which musn't necessarily exist. The `n` that your are citing is the width of the type, not related to its size. The standard says: "For unsigned integer types other than unsigned char, the bits of the object
representation shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits (there need
not be any of the latter)."

Comment: @Jens: Assume you have an n-bit representation, where the n bits are divided into v value bits and p padding bits.  Now the range is 0 .. 2**v - 1.  `(unsigned_type)-1` is required by the standard to be congruent to -1 modulo 2**n, and the smallest such non-negative number is 2**n - 1.  Therefore 2**n - 1 <= 2**v - 1, and hence n <= v.  But n = v + p so v + p <= v and p <= 0.  QED padding bits are impossible.

Comment: @Ben: I have no idea where you're getting this `n` from. The standard reads (6.3.1.3): "Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type". There is no language about modulo or 2 raised to the power of the number of representation bits. C clearly allows padding bits in unsigned types.

Comment: @R: Maybe the problem is that I'm citing the C++ standard and you're citing the C standard and, come to think of it, you said you were providing an answer for C.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Now it makes sense. I suspect this is a bug in the C++ standard that will hopefully be addressed in the next version. Anyway this discussion serves as a good reason why this question should have been split into two questions, one for C and one for C++, if OP really cared about the answers for both languages...

Comment: How about `if (x + 1 == 0)`?  This is guaranteed to work for **unsigned** types only, but that is exactly what we are dealing with here and it works regardless which unsigned type `x` is.  If the compiler is smart enough there might not even be an extra addition.

Comment: @jw013: It won't work for `unsigned char` and probably not for `unsigned short`. That's the whole point of the tricks in my answer.