# Is it safe to assign -1 to an unsigned int to get the max value?

Tags: c++, unsigned

Is it safe to assign -1 to an unsigned int, or other unsigned c++ data type, if I need to get the max value?

Is there any situation where it won't give me the highest value an unsigned data type can contain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing for a maximum unsigned value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539469/testing-for-a-maximum-unsigned-value)

Comment: @juergen That will work for unsigned int, but not for all other unsigned data types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To be on a safe side, use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`.
Casting -1 to unsigned would work on mainstream platforms, but it is not guaranteed by the standard AFAIR.

UPD: I'll correct myself. (unsigned)-1 is required to be UINT_MAX in C, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2760612/1345960)

Comment: Casting -1 to an `unsigned` type is guaranteed to work by the standard. The problem is that the intent isn't all that clear. With `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` it is very clear. Very verbose, also, but very clear.

Comment: Your update references a c question which in turn references the c standard. The c++ standard says that unsigned ints "shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^n". The end effect is the same.

Answer (score -1):

I *think* you'll be okay using -1 on any 2's complement machine (which I think is everything nowadays).

Comment: Ever heard of embedded systems?

Comment: Not any that support a C++ compiler that use 1s complement. Do you know of any?

Comment: I think there was once a question about odd platforms and there were a few examples of 1complements but they were C related. You might be right regarding C++.

Comment: From the standard: "Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^n where n is the num- ber of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer." In other words, unsigned ints are 2s complement even on a 1s complement machine.

Comment: @DavidHammen I understand what you are trying to say (which is correct), but 2s complement defines a way of representing negative numbers.  Since unsigned types can't represent negative numbers at all, they can't be 2s complement.  What you probably meant is that conversion from signed to unsigned behaves as if the 2s complement bit pattern were used for the unsigned.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yeah, it would have been better to say that how a machine represents negative numbers has no bearing on unsigned integers behave in c++, and that conversion from signed to unsigned proceeds as if the machine used 2s complement to represent negative numbers.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Although it happens that the behavior of the conversion behaves like two's complement, real reason that -1u is UINT_MAX is that UINT_MAX+1 yields zero.

Comment: @supercat: The reason UINT_MAX+1 yields zero is precisely because the standard dictates modulo 2^n arithmetic. -1 and UINT_MAX are the same number (modulo 2^n), where n is the number of bits in an unsigned int.