# Why does 4294967295 (the highest number at 32bit) equal -1?

Tags: c++

I have this simple part of my code:

```
int pch = name.find("#");
if(pch == name.npos) continue;
```

When in `name.find` doesn't find `"#"`, `pch` is equal to -1. `name.npos` instead, if I print it, is 4294967295. Why is it that in this case, when `pch` is -1 and `name.npos` is `4294967295`, the program enters the `if` condition?

Comment: What type does `name.find` return? What type is `name.npos`?

Comment: Why would you expect them to be different? Are you aware that arithmetic of 32 bits number is done modulus 2 power 32?

Comment: How do you print it?

Comment: `4294967295` is *not* the "highest number at 32 bit", it is the highest `unsigned int`. That value (`0xFFFFFFFF`) is `-1` when the variable is `int`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing for a maximum unsigned value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539469/testing-for-a-maximum-unsigned-value)

Comment: See [Using -1 as a flag value for unsigned (size_t) types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22801069/1708801) ... `-1` will always convert to the max unsigned value.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That is a better duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `string::npos` denotes that the position is not found. It is usually represented by a constant value of `-1`.

[Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/)

> This constant is defined with a value of -1, which because size_t is an unsigned integral type, it is the largest possible representable value for this type.

- In case, `find` is unsuccessful, it returns `-1`.

So, both are equal, in your case and the `if` is satisfied.

Now, to answer

> *`name.npos` instead, if I print it, is 4294967295*

because, `string::npos` is of type `size_t` which is usually `typedef` to `unsigned` type. The `-1`,which is used to initialize an `unsigned` type will be stored as and printing [the maximum possible unsigned value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22801069/2173917).

Comment: An interesting specification given that officially platforms can use one's complement, two's complement or signed magnitude and the conversion of signed to unsigned is undefined.. Only in two's complement is the bit-pattern for -1 also the greatest unsigned value.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the internal representation of negative numbers. This is called the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).