# How to fix this problem when reading a file in C++?

Tags: c++

so I was testing this program that I am making to conjugate japanese verbs from a text file that has 7 things (verb stem, infinitive, dictionary form, dictionary form (hiragana), dictionary form(kanji), and verb group. I am getting this error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 4294967295) >= this->size() (which is 1) and I have no idea how to fix it or whats wrong.  code snippet below. Thanks! I cant upload the text file though!
Functions.cpp file

```
#include "JapaneseConjugate.h"
void verbInit(verbType verbArray[VERBS], int &count, int flag, string fileName, string fileExtension, string filePath){
     string fileLine;
     string secondLine;
     string thirdLine;
     string fourthLine;
     string fifthLine;
     string sixthLine;
     string seventhLine;
     ifstream myFile (filePath + fileName + fileExtension);
     int currentIndex = 0;
     int passingInt = 0;
     if (myFile.is_open()){
         while (getline(myFile,fileLine)){
             verbType verb;
             verbArray[currentIndex] = verb;
             verbArray[currentIndex].verbEnding = fileLine.at(fileLine.length()-2) + fileLine.at(fileLine.length()-1);
             verbArray[currentIndex].verbStem = fileLine;
             getline(myFile,secondLine);
             verbArray[currentIndex].verbInfinitive = secondLine;
             getline(myFile,thirdLine);
             verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormRomaji = thirdLine;
             getline(myFile,fourthLine);
             verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormHiragana = fourthLine;
             if (verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "motsu" || verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "matsu"){
                 verb.verbEnding = "tsu";
             }else if (verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "arau" || verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "tsukau" ||
                       verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "omou" || verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "utau" ||
                       verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "iu" || verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "morau" ||
                       verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "harau" || verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "kau" ||
                       verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "au" || verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "narau"||
                       verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "warau" || verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "suu" ||
                       verb.dictionaryFormRomaji == "chigau"){
                 verb.verbEnding = "u";
             }else {
                 verb.verbEnding = fourthLine[fourthLine.length()-2] + fourthLine[fourthLine.length()-1];
             }
             if (flag == 1) {
                 getline(myFile,fifthLine);
                 verbArray[currentIndex].dictionaryFormKanji = fifthLine;
             }
             getline(myFile,sixthLine);
             cout << sixthLine << endl;
             verbArray[currentIndex].verbDefinition = "to " + sixthLine;
             getline(myFile,seventhLine);
             cout << seventhLine;
             system("PAUSE");
             passingInt = stoi(seventhLine);
             verbArray[currentIndex].verbGroup = passingInt;
             currentIndex++;
             count++;
        }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
       if (verbArray[i].verbGroup == 1){
           verbArray[i].presentTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masu";
           verbArray[i].presentTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masen";
           verbArray[i].presentTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji;
           verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "anai";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "mashita";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masendeshita";
           if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "u" || verbArray[i].verbEnding == "tsu" || verbArray[i].verbEnding == "ru"){
               verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "tta";
           }else if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "bu" || verbArray[i].verbEnding == "mu" || verbArray[i].verbEnding == "nu"){
               verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "nda";
           }else if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "ku"){
               verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "ita";
           }else if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "gu"){
               verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "ida";
           }else if (verbArray[i].verbEnding == "su"){
               verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "shita";
           }
           verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "anakatta";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "mashou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "anaideshou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji + "darou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative + "darou";

       }else if (verbArray[i].verbGroup == 2){
           verbArray[i].presentTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masu";
           verbArray[i].presentTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masen";
           verbArray[i].presentTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji;
           verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "nai";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "mashita";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masendeshita";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "ta";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "nakatta";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "mashou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "naideshou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji + "darou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative + "darou";
       }else {
           verbArray[i].presentTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masu";
           verbArray[i].presentTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masen";
           verbArray[i].presentTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji;
           verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "wanai";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "mashita";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "masendeshita";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "tta";
           verbArray[i].pastTense.plainNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "wanakatta";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.formalAffirmative = verbArray[i].verbInfinitive + "mashou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.formalNegative = verbArray[i].verbStem + "wanaideshou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].dictionaryFormRomaji + "darou";
           verbArray[i].volitionalTense.plainAffirmative = verbArray[i].presentTense.plainNegative + "darou";
       }
   }
}
```

Header file

```
#ifndef JAPANESECONJUGATE_H_
#define JAPANESECONJUGATE_H_

#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

const string sampleFile = "Japanese verbs";
const string sampleExtension = ".txt";
const string samplePath = "";
const int VERBS = 1000;
const int INT_MAX = 10000;

struct tenseType{
   string currentTense;
   string plainAffirmative;
   string plainNegative;
   string formalAffirmative;
   string formalNegative;
};

struct verbType{

    string verbStem;
    string verbInfinitive;
    string dictionaryFormRomaji;
    string dictionaryFormHiragana;
    string dictionaryFormKanji;
    string verbDefinition;
    int verbGroup;
    string verbEnding;

    tenseType presentTense;
    tenseType volitionalTense;
    tenseType imperativeTense;
    tenseType pastTense;
    tenseType pastPresumptiveTense;
    tenseType presentProgressiveTense;
    tenseType pastProgressiveTense;
    tenseType conditionalTense;
    tenseType causativeTense;
    tenseType passiveTense;
};

struct boxMemberType{
    verbType verb;
    tenseType tense;
    bool affirmative;
    bool formal;
};

struct nodeType{
    boxMemberType data;
    nodeType *next;
};

void printVerbs(verbType verbArray[VERBS], int count);
void verbInit(verbType verbArray[VERBS], int &count, int flag, string fileName = sampleFile, string fileExtension = sampleExtension, string filePath = samplePath);

#endif
```

Comment: Use your debugger. See what the values of everything are when it crashes. What debugger are you using?

Comment: Looks like you may be accessing `fileLine` at index `-1`, which probably not what you intend to do...

Comment: When you get numbers like this`4294967295` google may help. Here is one of the links I found: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246843/why-does-4294967295-the-highest-number-at-32bit-equal-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246843/why-does-4294967295-the-highest-number-at-32bit-equal-1)

Comment: What happens if your input file has a line containing less than 2 characters?

Comment: Probably `fileLine.length()-2` underflows or `fourthLine.length()-2` or ....