# Read of Chirp Sensor return only big same values

Tags: c++, sensors, nodemcu

several months ago i bought some plant sensor on ali express called "chirp plant watering alarm 2.4". https://wemakethings.net/chirp/

I tried the sample code of them to read and control the sensors over a d1 mini.
Sadly i only get the same value everytime. `4294967295` for every i2c read on every sensor. I connect the SDA/SDC Pins like in the pinout on there website.

The Sample Code:

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void writeI2CRegister8bit(int addr, int value) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
  Wire.write(value);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

unsigned int readI2CRegister16bit(int addr, int reg) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
  Wire.write(reg);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(1100);
  Wire.requestFrom(addr, 2);
  unsigned int t = Wire.read() << 8;
  t = t | Wire.read();
  return t;
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(readI2CRegister16bit(0x20, 0)); //read capacitance register
  writeI2CRegister8bit(0x20, 3); //request light measurement 
  delay(9000);                   //this can take a while
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(readI2CRegister16bit(0x20, 4)); //read light register
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: `4294967295` is [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246843/why-does-4294967295-the-highest-number-at-32bit-equal-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246843/why-does-4294967295-the-highest-number-at-32bit-equal-1)

Comment: My expectation is you are not communicating with device. Maybe a problem with the wires.

Comment: I double checked the wiring and tried several of this sensor and another d1 mini :( no changes