# Negative or Positive Number to 32 Bit Binary Data in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to convert a number to 32 Bit binary data. When I try to convert a number to 16 bit or 8 bit data, there is no any problem. But When I try 32 Bit, result is not correct.

8 Bit example:

`-1 & 255 //result -> 255` or `-1 & 0xFF //result -> 255`

16 Bit example:

`-1 & 65535 //result -> 65535` or `-1 & 0xFFFF //result -> 65535`

Wrong result in 32 Bit

`-1 & 4294967295 //result -> -1` or `-1 & 0xFFFFFFFF //result -> 4294967295`

My expectation in 32 bit, result is 4294967295. `-1` is not a correct answer.

How can solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: Two's compliment? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement Possible answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246843/why-does-4294967295-the-highest-number-at-32bit-equal-1 or     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863153/why-unsigned-int-0xffffffff-is-equal-to-int-1

Comment: I already do that. but it does not work for 32 bit data :) @RobinWebb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer of my question.

this is not working for 32 bit

`-1 & 4294967295`

this is working for 32 bit

`-1 >>> 0 //result -> 4294967295`

but I don't understand the reason of this error.